# Construct quadkey grid in PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I would like to create a set of grids in quadkey format like this Mapbox site shows https://labs.mapbox.com/what-the-tile/

Is there any solution in PostGIS that given an boundingbox.geom and the zoom level the function construct the grid with the quadkey attribute id.